# Bug : SwipeRefreshLayout view doesn't get removed from Fragment container

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

My application contains a drawer with two `Fragments`. Each `Fragment` contains a layout with `SwipeRefreshLayout` view.

If I replace `Fragment` in container when `SwipeRefreshLayout` is refreshing, the view of the fragment gets stuck in the `FrameLayout` container and appears above the new `Fragment` View. However, old fragment is removed from the `FragmentManager`.

Application works fine if I replace the `Fragment` in container when `SwipeRefreshLayout` is not refreshing. You can access the demo bug project [here](https://github.com/jimmy0251/SwipeRefreshLayoutBug.git).

Any workaround or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in `SwipeRefreshLayout` which is not fixed from long time despite having enough stars. You can keep track of issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712).

Answer (score 3):

Calling 'clearAnimation()' of your SwipeRefreshLayout before you replace the Fragment should do the trick.